# Unofficial Stack Overflow deleted question archive now available

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, archive

With a modified version of my [so-static](https://github.com/ghewgill/so-static) tools, along with all the historical data dumps, I've made an archive of all deleted questions (and their answers) from Stack Overflow.

The site is no longer live but archived location is: https://web.archive.org/web/20180317053811/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/

Here's the top five:

> 1240 [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180317052940/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/723/94.html)
>   913 [I'm graduating with a Computer Science degree but I don't feel like I know how to program.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311144430/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/282/357/1.html)
>   840 [What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311144430/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/845/56.html)
>   831 [What is your best programmer joke?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311144430/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/234/075.html)
>   695 [Senior programming 'guru' who can't program - should I find a different career?](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311144430/http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/124/605/8.html)

Note that some of the questions identified as "deleted" were actually migrated to a different site and *then* deleted from SO (the first one is an example of this).

No attempt has been made to archive linked media such as images.

Comment: I'd put "unofficial" in the title of this or something, it seems misleading.

Comment: Does it? I've added "unofficial" to the text.

Comment: Just because they've talked about an official archive.  I assumed this was it from the title before clicking through, anyways.  Thanks!

Comment: Attribution could be clearer (on the "question" page)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there was talk of an official one. All I knew about was http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61221/deleted-questions-archive and related ones.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I've used the same code I already had for generating the [Kindle books](http://stackapps.com/questions/2035/stack-overflow-ebooks-for-kindle), so it's fairly compact. What might you suggest?

Comment: @GregHewgill They just mentioned an official one in the [podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer/), but I don't know if they're actually working on one or not

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Ah, thanks! I'm a bit behind on the podcast and hadn't seen that one yet.

Comment: I thought I'd have a go at the CSS thing, but the markup is terrible. Any chance you'll clean up the markup to standard HTML and add some hooks (`id` or `class`) for the CSS?

Comment: You couldn't have done this a month ago? \*sigh\*  J/K great stuff!

Comment: Sorry its been a very long time since I've looked at the data dumps, but weren't deleted questions and answers removed a long time ago from the data dumps?

Comment: @TheLQ: Deleted questions have never been part of data dumps. However, deleting a question doesn't reach out and change the old data dumps that currently exist on my hard drive.

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_: Ok, new HTML is generating now. You might recognise the styles. :)

Comment: @casperOne No. If he'd done it a month ago it's less likely that Stack Exchange would be considering an an official archive. I had begun to hope that nobody would put together an unofficial archive, because it would hurt our changes of SEI taking responsibility. (No offence to Greg Hewgill, this is nice work.)

Comment: Yes, it **is** nice work! @GregHewgill This is probably excessive, but I don't supposed you were considering, possibly, doing this for any other StackExchange sites?

Comment: @FeralOink: This was more of a proof of concept. I expect that a deleted question archive will at some point be hosted by Stack Exchange.

Comment: OK, but where is that questions about programming antipatters, with joda clauses, ninja comments and egyptian brackets?

Comment: @GregHewgill : I've noticed some Unicode snafu in there (e.g., at the "56" answer on http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/124/605/8.html ), but we can't be sure if it was originally like that, or it's a bug in your processing or archived data, or a bug in the display...

Comment: @C.B.: Oops. Not sure how that happened, the data was originally correct on SO but got translated to an actual question mark somewhere along the way. Oh well.

Comment: What about the boat question?

Comment: Sow how can I find my deleted answers? I have 5 deleted answers that I have no way of finding them. If @Oded could please send me some links or something I will gladly fix them. I am trying to get my reputation so I can contribute even if it is a little bit.

Comment: @GregHewgill Is the archive updated? I am trying to find this question on your archive but couldn't 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories

Comment: @OzairKafray: Sorry, I haven't updated the deleted question archive in a couple of years. That question was deleted in April 2013.

Comment: I'm looking for a mirror of [Modern alternatives to R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983222/modern-alternatives-to-r). It has negative votes. Are those questions excluded from the archive?

Comment: Comments are missing ?!

Comment: @GregHewgill thank you for saving these for posterity. It's sad when a site deletes popular content that the community has contributed in good faith.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because following a server change, the owner of this archive has taken this down. See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50307038#50307038) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

I'll answer the question I see in the question ("contributors?") regarding CSS.

Here are two projects that may help:

- [StackOverflow viewer in static HTML](http://danlec.com/blog/stackoverflow-in-4096-bytes)
- a [StackApps StackOverflow clone](https://stackapps.com/questions/3/sample-application-worlds-worst-stackoverflow-clone/4562)

Comment: The second link is dead.