# Is there any way for a user to view a summary of deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I have over 10k rep so I can view deleted questions, but is there any way to view a list or summary of deleted questions?

I'd be willing to try a stack app if the information is available there. I already tried using [Data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), but it apparently doesn't include deleted questions.

Comment: [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/deleted).

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today) what you're after? It only lists recent deletions, though.

Comment: @balpha Something like that, but for older items as well

Comment: [This is another one](http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/) - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available

Comment: @assylias Great link, thank you. Most of the time I want to find older high-scoring questions, so that works fairly well. Do you know if there's something similar for other SE sites? In particular, Programmers.SE?

Comment: @Rachel nope...

Answer (score 2):

You can see a list of [recently deleted posts (link to SO mod tools)](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=delete&daterange=today) in the moderator tools.

That list is limited to 50 items though, and includes both answers and questions.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that link, however that only gets me the most recent items, and I wanted to look at older items

Comment: @Rachel: yup; that's the *only* listing I know of though.