# I wonder why this question was deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

http://stackoverflow.hewgill.com/questions/234/075.html

The above link is a collection of some great programming jokes.
but for some reason it is not on the main site but in some kind of archive. I wonder what was the logic behind removing this from the website and maintaining an archive.

P.S. the reason why i thought this question is deleted is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124850/201081)

Comment: [It's not deleted.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke) It's just historically locked.

Comment: @Mysticial ok.then what about the archive on hewgill.com? why two copies of the same question.

Comment: hewgill.com, is not affiliated with SO. It's the website of [Greg Hewgill](http://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) a long-time SO user.

Comment: In some ways, a duplicate of this question: [Why was «What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon» deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73412)

Answer (score 7):

The question itself, on Stack Overflow has gotten a historical lock (it is not deleted).

Why locked? Because it is actually an example of a question not suitable for Stack Overflow. It is a poll and goes against what is currently acceptable for a question.

Why is it not deleted? Because it was very popular and was asked at a time where the rules were not as strict. It is part of the history and evolution of the site.

Why an archive? Ask Greg Hewgill - it is his site. It is not part of Stack Exchange. Guess he liked some questions/answers enough to host a permanent archive of them.

Comment: i thought it was deleted because: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124850/201081

Comment: @MayankSharma - At a certain time it _was_ deleted. But later on it got undeleted. Posts are rarely gone to such an extent that they cannot be recovered.