# How to access deleted question via data explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, deleted-questions, data-dump

Deleted questions only get soft-deleted. They are not shown anymore,
  (but accessible to >10k-rep-users). Thus, they should be available
  via the data dump.

How would you access, say, [what-stack-overflow-is-not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not)?

---

It was alleged that this question is a duplicate of [can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157462/can-some-metadata-about-deleted-posts-be-included-in-data-se).

The duplicate-origin contains the information (in the question, it has no answers) that the data dump does not contain deleted questions, yet [unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available?rq=1) offers deleted SO questions. Thus, it might be possible.

Comment: The duplicate-origin **does not have an answer**. Additionally, it seems possible to retrieve deleted questions, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124850/unofficial-stack-overflow-deleted-question-archive-now-available?rq=1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like your way of reasoning but if the deleted posts were available in the data dump or SEDE it would defeat having the privilege on the sites in the first place.

Deleted content is deleted for a reason by community members. If the OP thinks that deletion is incorrect a question can be raised on meta where several community members can decide if an undelete is needed.

So, you don't access [What Stack Overflow is Not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not) until you got 10K or a 10K-er is kind enough to provide you with a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErnPO.jpg).

Comment: lol +1 for the screenshot! :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ .. and you didn't complain I forgot to add page 2 of the answers ... ;)

Comment: That is so much great guidance. One wonders why it was deleted.

Comment: The question and all answers are written to describe *negative* behavior. I can see how, if presented to newbies, that post conveys a not welcoming message. Most of the guidance is duplicated in the help center where more focus is on the what we expect from users and stimulate/reward positive behavior..