# Stack Overflow Data Dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump

The Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump was released sometime back.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/

I read that the data is upto september 2011. So does it imply it will include all questions asked till 30th September, 2011 (so even if some of the questions asked on 30th do not receive an answer, they will be included, am I right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent data dump is actually from [August, 2012](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/2076-aug-2012), and yes, it contains all content posted up until the date the data dump was generated (2012-08-05).

As a side note, more regular data dumps are something in consideration as a low-priority item. There was also a desire to post data dumps as an [Amazon public data set](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117178/can-the-stack-exchange-data-dump-be-provided-as-a-public-data-set-on-amazon-web), but so far it doesn't look like anything's come of that.

Comment: Thanks for the dump list !