# When might a newer data-dump be created?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, data-dump

There is an August 2012 data dump.  That was a long long time ago (here near the end of January 2013).  Will another one be done anytime soon?

It went from "every 2 months" to "quarterly" to (apparently) "when we feel like it."  Consistency could be quite important to anyone thinking of taking advantage of the dump.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164090/161198

Comment: I'd *love* to see a new dump made available.

Answer (score 8):

It took us a while to get there, but the March 2013 data dump is up:

http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump

We hope to have more regular dumping occurring from now on.